# What processes are running on which CPU?

Tags: cpu, monitoring, top

Running "top" shows you how much CPU power is used by each process.

Suppose you have several CPUs. Is there a utility that shows you the same information as top, but for each individual CPU?

For example, if this utility is called "topp" then "topp 1" would show all the processes that run on CPU number 1, and how much power of that CPU that take. Is there such a program?

Comment: The decision about which CPU to run on is made every time a process is selected by the scheduler, multiple times a second. Your display can't keep up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is ... `top`. From [`man top`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/top.1.html):

```
12. P  --  Last used CPU (SMP)
    A  number representing the last used processor.  In a true SMP
    environment this  will  likely  change  frequently  since  the
    kernel  intentionally  uses weak affinity.  Also, the very act
    of running top may break this weak  affinity  and  cause  more
    processes  to  change  CPUs  more  often (because of the extra
    demand for cpu time).
```

When running `top`, you can apply filters to the processes shown. Press `?` to see the help:

[image]

As mentioned, to filter, press <kbd>o</kbd>(after exiting the help), then type `P=N`, where `N` is the desired CPU number:

[image]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The processes should now be only those that last ran on CPU 0.

Note that the defaault list of columns does not include the CPU number. Press <kbd>f</kbd> to change the fields:

[image]

Move to `P` and press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to select it. When you exit the help, the column should be there:

[image]